# Issue with Layout Design having the two buttons

Tags: javascript, android, android-layout, layout

I would like to design the layout which satisfies the following requirements :

**1.** There are two buttons initially. One next to the other

[image]

**2.** If i need to increase the text of the button1 the button2 with move towards the right

[image]

**3.** Here is the problem, when you increase the text much more,the button2 shrinks, which i dont want, I want to the button2 to not be shrinked and the button1 should be.

[image]

The design should look like presented on the screenshots.

**How can I design the layout in presented way ?**

Comment: i cant use weight because the expansion of buttons based on the text inside the button

Comment: you can avoid that by setting android:singleline to true see my ans

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: This design fails the 1 screen shot..please once check giving the  small text to the buttons

Comment: no it will not fail to ur screen shot 1. Check properly. Give width 0 dp to thye buttons

Comment: The width of the buttons must not be half of the parent..the width must depends on the text of the buttons..check the screen shot1 clearly

Answer (score 0):

There are few options to achieve this.

1. Use LinearLayout add `weightSum="3"` and give `layout_weight="integer"` to childs.
   This has to be of the ratio format **ex: 2 : 1** in this case also make sure the `layout_width="0dp"`
2. Use `Relative Layout`, place **button2** to the `right_of` **button1** and give `min_width="100dp"`(adjust the size) to **button2**

Comment: Please check the Note added to the Question. thank you

Comment: @user3607798 use my `2` option, this will satisfy all the above.

Comment: i'm sorry..the button2 still shrinking

Answer (score 0):

Use following one in your layout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/TextView07"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button1 fgdfg Belgian Alesfghdfgh  dfgdfgddfgdfn drg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/levadura_data_mejor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.001"
        android:text="Button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Its working for me. Meeting to all your requirements.

Comment: Try with small text for the button1...it will not satisfy the ScreenShot1

Comment: Sorry boss! but its working for me with small text also. I think you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

It's working for all devices as well.

Comment: Please check the note added to the Question

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your button in another linear layout for this to work. This is how I do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Button is really really long haha" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Once check the answer by reducing the text for the button1

Comment: I know it shrinks because it is set to wrap content just change it to match parent you need to do things on your own too we are just here to help at our own way and we expect to be helped too anyways I will edit my ans

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could get. If you can figure out how to make it left aligned instead of right aligned in your overall layout, it will match the requirements you listed:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/test_button_0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Normal" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/test_button_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/test_button_0"
    android:lines="1"
    android:text="This could be very, very, very, long..." >
</Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

By using a relative layout instead of a linear layout, this method can put the button that goes on the right, first in the XML code. The child that comes first is the one that the layout manager will not squeeze, it seems.